# Mask content to get height of image side-by-side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have some rows containing an image in the left column, and some text in the right column. The image has a ratio of 16:9. When the text gets long, I want to mask the text with a gradient, and show the "Read more" button as demonstrated below (current layout to the left, wanted layout to the right):

[image: Demo image]

Using Bootstrap 4, alpha 6.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/losol/pen/BZJKBx)

```css
.bg-gray-950 {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.bg-gradient-red-green {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4cad9e, #b34b4b);
  color: #fff;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000000, #dc4425);
    opacity: .3;
  }
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(33, 66, 99, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container m-5">
  <div class="row bg-gray-950 d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 p-0 img-overlay">
      <img src="https://losol.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/20170502-2054-hovland-05091.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Lorem hipster dolor ipsum sit amet</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Dreamcatcher kombucha drinking vinegar cold-pressed hoodie craft beer literally blog microdosing trust organic flannel blue bottle fingerstache. Blog skateboard cronut chips brunch pug. Heirloom coloring book, pitchfork flannel bicycle rights
          deep v meditation. </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippet is not working

Comment: Sorry, corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note that this is an incomplete answer. This is just to cover the transparency of the text and not the fitting of the content. your example code is not complete*

---

I am able to achieve the desired effect by adding:

```
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))
```

to the text class.

Nice and simple, right? **No**.

This won't work on [IE or Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) but still...89% support is not too shabby.

```css
.bg-gray-950 {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.bg-gradient-red-green {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4cad9e, #b34b4b);
  color: #fff;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000000, #dc4425);
    opacity: .3;
  }
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #5f514c !important;
}



.card-text {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container m-5">
    <div class="row bg-gray-950 d-flex">
      <div class="col-md-6 p-0 img-overlay">
        <img src="https://losol.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/20170502-2054-hovland-05091.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Lorem hipster dolor ipsum sit amet</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque urbanitas est at. Graeci eloquentiam nam ad. Vix ut laudem aperiam accumsan, ut illum ubique feugait mel, munere incorrupte usu eu. At his cibo suscipit. His ex nobis scaevola.
Qui ex mundi inimicus iracundia. Ne eruditi noluisse est, mei unum apeirian te, mucius accusata ne qui. Aliquid ancillae conceptam sed ex. Ius semper aperiri te</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is first make sure the div holding the text is the same height as the image. You can do that by giving it height: 0 and padding-top: 56.25%; (forces a 16:9 ratio).
The next step is to put the button in a div that also holds the gradient and position it absolute at the bottom of the div.

I've put together a quick and dirty demo here:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper > img {
  float: left;
}

.textdiv {
  width: 640px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.textdiv__inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  
}

.button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 50px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 0%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="" />
  <div class="textdiv">
    <div class="textdiv__inner">
      <p class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sint nesciunt temporibus accusamus dicta eum soluta, distinctio, aspernatur iste adipisci praesentium, quae vitae molestiae non, quasi eligendi laborum deleniti ratione!
      </p>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! This is the "final" code, just publishing it in case anyone else is googling it.

```css
  

.bg-gradient-wipe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #fff 75%);
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #fff 75%);
}

.btn-fixed-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.bg-gray-950 {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-overlay:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #000000, #dc4425);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000000, #dc4425);
  opacity: .3;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #336699!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<div class="container m-5">
  <div class="row bg-gray-950 d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 p-0 img-overlay">
      <img src="https://losol.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/20170502-2054-hovland-05091.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <div class="embed-responsive-item p-3">
        <div class="bg-gradient-wipe"></div>
        <h4>Lorem hipster dolor ipsum sit amet</h4>
        <p>Dreamcatcher kombucha drinking vinegar cold-pressed hoodie craft beer literally blog microdosing trust organic flannel blue bottle fingerstache. Blog skateboard cronut chips brunch pug. Heirloom coloring book, pitchfork flannel bicycle rights deep v meditation. </p>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-fixed-bottom btn-outline-primary rounded-0"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Read more</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't even remotely looks the same as the accepted answer...and you image sample?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the links to bootstrap css/js. Looks good now.